# Valgrind error when writing (fwrite) a struct array into binary file

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, malloc

The goal of my program is to read a list of people from the standard input and be able to write and read them onto binary files. Each person in the list is a `tPessoa` structure containing three string variables. Since, I'm trying to read an unspecified number of people, I'm using "pointer to pointer" to make an array of structs.

When I execute the compiled script with `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes`, I get the following error:

```
==1211042== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==1211042==    at 0x4986A77: write (write.c:26)
==1211042==    by 0x48FCEEC: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1180)
==1211042==    by 0x48FE9E0: new_do_write (fileops.c:448)
==1211042==    by 0x48FE9E0: _IO_new_do_write (fileops.c:425)
==1211042==    by 0x48FE9E0: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:422)
==1211042==    by 0x48FDFD7: _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:135)
==1211042==    by 0x48F0D8E: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:53)
==1211042==    by 0x1095A7: EscrevePessoasBinario (ex.c:68)
==1211042==    by 0x109704: main (ex.c:107)
==1211042==  Address 0x4a9e965 is 21 bytes inside a block of size 4,096 alloc'd
==1211042==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1211042==    by 0x48F0BA3: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==1211042==    by 0x48FFCDF: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==1211042==    by 0x48FEF5F: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:744)
==1211042==    by 0x48FD6D4: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1243)
==1211042==    by 0x48FD6D4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1196)
==1211042==    by 0x48F1FD6: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==1211042==    by 0x109572: EscrevePessoasBinario (ex.c:60)
==1211042==    by 0x109704: main (ex.c:107)
==1211042==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1211042==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1211042==    by 0x109384: LePessoasInput (ex.c:28)
==1211042==    by 0x1096EF: main (ex.c:106)
==1211042== 
==1211042== 
==1211042== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1211042==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1211042==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 14,666 bytes allocated
==1211042== 
==1211042== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1211042== 
==1211042== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1211042== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

By the way, I'm leaving my entire code at the end of the post so anyone can make their tests and investigations.

Here's what I have found so far.

Valgrind says I'm trying to operate on an uninitialized value, and I believe that means I could be writing garbage to the binary file and that triggers the error. Valgrind says I'm doing that on line 68, but that doesn't seem to be correct. On line 68, `fclose(arquivo)` is called and the `FILE` pointer gets freed (nothing unsual here). So I figured the error is elsewhere in that function and, after commenting out some parts, I found the error happens on `if ( fwrite(pessoas[pessoa], sizeof(tPessoa), 1, arquivo) != 1)`. That makes sense because the error seems to be about writing uninitialized values to the binary file.

Valgrind also says the unitialized value is being created on line 28, `pessoas[(*nPessoas) - 1] = (tPessoa *) malloc(sizeof(tPessoa));`. On line 28, I allocate memory for another `tPessoa` struct in the `pessoas` array. However, I can't see how that struct could be uninitialized, since I pass values to the struct's variables right after allocating memory for it. My suspect I'm allocating 100 bytes for the `nome` (name in Portuguese) variable, but I don't necessarily pass 99 characters plus the '\0' because not all names are that long. So if a person's name is 15 characters long, that means 16 bytes (counting the `'\0'`) leaving another 84 bytes uninitialized.

Could the problem be the `nome` variable and its unitialized characters? If so, how can I solve this.

If not, I'll leave the entire code below, so anyone can make their on conclusions. Any suggestions are welcome. I'd also like to have a better understanding on what Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)` really means. Valgrind errors are sort of enigmatic to me.

P.S.: I'm compiling the code with `gcc -g`.

**The code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ex
{
    char nome[100];
    char dataNascimento[11];
    char cpf[15];
} tPessoa;

void DesalocaPessoas(tPessoa** pessoas, int nPessoas) {
    for (int pessoa = 0; pessoa < nPessoas; pessoa++) {
        free(pessoas[pessoa]);
    }
    free(pessoas);
}

tPessoa** LePessoasInput(int* nPessoas) {
    tPessoa **pessoas = (tPessoa**) malloc(sizeof(tPessoa *));
    //pessoas[0] = (tPessoa*) malloc(sizeof(tPessoa));
    char controle = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        (*nPessoas)++;
        pessoas = (tPessoa **) realloc(pessoas, sizeof(tPessoa*) * (*nPessoas));
        pessoas[(*nPessoas) - 1] = (tPessoa *) malloc(sizeof(tPessoa));
        
        printf("----------- NOVA PESSOA -----------\n");
        printf("Nome: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", pessoas[(*nPessoas)-1]->nome);
        printf("Data de nascimento: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", pessoas[(*nPessoas)-1]->dataNascimento);
        printf("CPF: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", pessoas[(*nPessoas)-1]->cpf);
        while(1){
            printf("\nDeseja adicionar outra pessoa? [s/n] ");
            scanf("%c%*c", &controle);
            printf("\n");
            if ( controle == 'n' || controle == 'N' ) break;
            else if ( controle == 's' || controle == 'S' ) break;
        }
        if ( controle == 'n' || controle == 'N' ) break;   
    }

    return pessoas;
}

void EscrevePessoasBinario(tPessoa** pessoas, int nPessoas) {
    FILE *arquivo;
    int pessoasGravadas = 0;
    arquivo = fopen("pessoas.bin", "wb");

    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    
    for ( int pessoa = 0; pessoa < nPessoas; pessoa++ ) {
        if ( fwrite(pessoas[pessoa], sizeof(tPessoa), 1, arquivo) != 1 ) {
            fclose(arquivo);
            return;
        }
        pessoasGravadas++;
    }
    
    printf("Pessoas gravadas: %d\n", pessoasGravadas);
    fclose(arquivo);
}

void ImprimePessoasBinario(int nPessoas) {
    FILE *arquivo;
    tPessoa* pessoaLida = (tPessoa*) malloc(sizeof(tPessoa));

    arquivo = fopen("pessoas.bin", "rb");

    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        free(pessoaLida);
        return;
    }

    int nPessoasLidas = 0;

    for (int pessoa = 0; pessoa < nPessoas; pessoa++) {
        if (fread(pessoaLida, sizeof(tPessoa), 1, arquivo) != 1) {
            break;
        }

        nPessoasLidas++;
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("%s\n", pessoaLida->nome);
        printf("%s\n", pessoaLida->dataNascimento);
        printf("%s\n", pessoaLida->cpf);
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    }

    printf("Pessoas lidas: %d\n", nPessoasLidas);

    free(pessoaLida);
    fclose(arquivo);
}

int main() {
    int nPessoas = 0;

    tPessoa** pessoas = LePessoasInput(&nPessoas);
    EscrevePessoasBinario(pessoas, nPessoas);
    ImprimePessoasBinario(nPessoas);
    DesalocaPessoas(pessoas, nPessoas);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is correct: the structures `tPessoa` are allocated via `malloc()` which does not initialize them. The fields are read using `scanf()` which only sets the destination bytes for the characters read from `stdin` and the null terminator. This leaves parts of the structures uninitialized, and when `fwrite()` writes the whole structure to the file, some of the bytes written are still uninitialized, thus have an undeterminate value, which is what Valgrind protests about.

`fwrite` actually copies the structure contents to the stream buffer. At some point, the stream buffer in turn gets written to the file by internal functions such as `_IO_do_write` or other obscure library functions, either indirectly by `fwrite()` or `fclose()` (`fflush` or `fseek` could flush the stream buffer to disk too.)  Valgrind does not complain immediately about `fwrite` copying uninitialized data, but seems to keep track of these bytes and complains when they are finally used or written to disk.

To prevent the Valgrind message, use `calloc()` to allocate the structures:

```
    pessoas[(*nPessoas) - 1] = (tPessoa *)calloc(sizeof(tPessoa), 1);
```

Note also that `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", pessoas[(*nPessoas)-1]->nome)` and the following calls cannot prevent buffer overflows if the input stream contains lines longer than the destination arrays. You should specify the maximum number of characters to store or use a custom function that can perform the appropriate tests.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct tPessoa {
    char nome[100];
    char dataNascimento[11];
    char cpf[15];
} tPessoa;

void DesalocaPessoas(tPessoa **pessoas, int nPessoas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nPessoas; i++) {
        free(pessoas[i]);
    }
    free(pessoas);
}

char *ReadString(const char *prompt, char *dest, size_t size) {
    size_t i = 0;
    int c;

    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    fflush(stdout);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (i + 1 < size) {
            dest[i++] = (char)c;
        }
    }
    if (size) {
        dest[i] = '\0';
    }
    printf("\n");
    // return dest unless at end of file
    return (c == EOF && i == 0) ? NULL : dest;
}

tPessoa **LePessoasInput(int *nPessoas_ptr) {
    tPessoa **pessoas = NULL;
    int nPessoas = 0;

    for (;;) {
        tPessoa pessoa = { 0 };

        printf("----------- NOVA PESSOA -----------\n");
        if (!ReadString("Nome", pessoa.nome, sizeof pessoa.nome)
        ||  !ReadString("Data de nascimento", pessoa.dataNascimento, sizeof pessoa.dataNascimento)
        ||  !ReadString("CPF", pessoa.cpf, sizeof pessoa.cpf)) {
            /* input failure */
            break;
        }
        pessoas = (tPessoa **)realloc(pessoas, sizeof(tPessoa *) * (nPessoas + 1));
        pessoas[nPessoas] = (tPessoa *)calloc(sizeof(tPessoa), 1);
        *(pessoas[nPessoas]) = pessoa;
        nPessoas += 1;

        char controle = 'n';
        for (;;) {
            printf("Deseja adicionar outra pessoa? [s/n] ");
            scanf(" %c%*c", &controle);
            printf("\n");
            if (strchr("nNsSyY", controle))
                break;
        }
        if (controle == 'n' || controle == 'N')
            break;
    }
    *nPessoas_ptr = nPessoas;
    return pessoas;
}

void EscrevePessoasBinario(tPessoa **pessoas, int nPessoas) {
    int pessoasGravadas = 0;
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("pessoas.bin", "wb");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nPessoas; i++) {
        if (fwrite(pessoas[i], sizeof(tPessoa), 1, arquivo) != 1) {
            fclose(arquivo);
            return;
        }
        pessoasGravadas++;
    }

    printf("Pessoas gravadas: %d\n", pessoasGravadas);
    fclose(arquivo);
}

void ImprimePessoasBinario(int nPessoas) {
    tPessoa pessoa = { 0 };
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("pessoas.bin", "rb");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    int nPessoasLidas = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nPessoas; i++) {
        if (fread(&pessoa, sizeof(tPessoa), 1, arquivo) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        nPessoasLidas++;
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("%s\n", pessoa.nome);
        printf("%s\n", pessoa.dataNascimento);
        printf("%s\n", pessoa.cpf);
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    }

    printf("Pessoas lidas: %d\n", nPessoasLidas);
    fclose(arquivo);
}

int main(void) {
    int nPessoas = 0;
    tPessoa **pessoas = LePessoasInput(&nPessoas);
    EscrevePessoasBinario(pessoas, nPessoas);
    ImprimePessoasBinario(nPessoas);
    DesalocaPessoas(pessoas, nPessoas);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @chqrlie! Using calloc to allocate the structures solved the problem. So calloc initializes all elements of the structure to 0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/calloc?view=msvc-170). In this case, since the structure's elements are strings, calloc will allocate n bytes for n characters in the string and set each character to '\0'. Is that correct?

Comment: @VitorRodrigues:  The structure `tPessoa` is just a block of 126 bytes, which `calloc` initializes to all bits 0, which makes the array members `nome`, `dataNascimento` and `cpf` empty strings. `nome` is the first 100 bytes, `dataNascimento` the next 11 bytes and `cpf` the last 15 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

> On line 68, `fclose(arquivo)` is called and the `FILE` pointer gets freed (nothing unsual here).

`FILE`-based streams are buffered by default, and `fclose()` can and will write to a file opened for writing.  Per [**7.21.5.1 The fclose function**, paragraph 2 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.1p2) (bolding mine):

> A successful call to the fclose function causes the stream pointed to by stream to be flushed and the associated file to be closed. **Any unwritten buffered data for the stream are delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; ...**

A call to `fclose()` can therefore write uninitialized memory to your file, which means Valgrind is correct in identifying it.

You really should be checking the value returned from `fclose()`.

You can also explicitly call `fflush()` and check the return value from that to force buffered data to be written.

> My suspect I'm allocating 100 bytes for the nome (name, in English) variable, but I don't necessarily pass 99 characters plus the '\0' because not all names are that long. So if a person's name is 15 characters long, that means 16 bytes (counting the '\0') leaving another 84 bytes unitialized.

That will in fact result in reading and then writing uninitialized data as bytes returned from `malloc()` are [explicitly not inititialized](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4p2):

> The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

You can either call `memset()` to explicitly set the contents of the entire buffer, or you can replace `malloc()` with `calloc()` to ensure the entire buffer is set to zeros when you allocate it.  Given you're reading data from the user and doing file IO operations, the performance difference won't be measurable at all.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Replacing malloc() with calloc() did solve the problem. Could you elaborate a little more on how and where I could use fflush() "to force buffered data to be written [to the binary file, I believe]"? I have little familiarity to fflush(), therefore it's difficult to me seeing how I could use it.